# Copy complete sentences from text file and add to list

Tags: python, string, list, text

I am trying to extract **complete sentences** from a long text file and adding them as strings to a list in Python 2.7. I want to automate this and not just cut and paste in the list.

Here is what I have:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv # script = alien.py; filename = roswell.txt

listed = []

text = open(filename, 'rw')

for i in text:
    lines = readline(i)
    listed.append(lines)

print listed
text.close()
```

Nothing loads to the list.

Comment: `for i in text` already reads each line in the file, what is `readline(i)` for (and where is it from)? If you just want all of the lines, why not `listed = text.readlines()`? Also, you should use the *"context manager"* `with open(...) as text:`.

Comment: Define _complete sentences_. Also, show us what the function `readline` does. It is not part of standard library. However, there is a method `readline` that can be called on file-like objects. Provide the content of your text file (or part of it) and the list that you want to get

Comment: So are the lines of your file already complete sentences and you just want to read the file line by line or is there more to it? (Such as detecting when sentences end...)

Comment: You should show at least some of your input file.  As @jonrsharpe pointed out, i is the line, and lines - readline(i) doesn't make sense.  Also you open your file with 'rw' which is wrong.  Modes are 'r', 'w', 'a' and some others but not 'rw'.  And you are not writing to the file

Comment: Thank you. The file is eight chapters of a book in .pdf.

Comment: I hope to snatch each complete sentence, convert each to a string that Python understands, then load them into a list.

Comment: A pdf file is not a text file.  There are libraries that help reading pdfs

Comment: So just imagine a text file that had been converted to a text file with no illustrations, just sentences, all of which are to be loaded to a list.

Comment: I used poppler-utils pdftotext to make the .txt version. Poppler-utils is awesome !!

Comment: @johnsharpe Thank you for the input. I have the .txt which was converted from a .pdf with poppler-utils.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a while loop:

```
listed = []
with open(filename,"r") as text:
    Line = text.readline()


    while Line!='':
        listed.append(Line)
        Line = text.readline()

print listed
```

In the previous example, I assumed that each sentence is written on a different line, if that's not the case, use this code instead:

```
listed = []


with open(filename,"r") as text:
    Line = text.readline()


    while Line!='':
        Line1 = Line.split(".")
        for Sentence in Line1:
            listed.append(Sentence)
        Line = text.readline()

print listed
```

And on a side note, try using `with open(...) as text:` instead of `text = open(...)`

Comment: words separated by '.' are not necessary to form a sentence, for example, 10 A.M

Comment: @lulyon You are correct. I don't know what's inside the text file though. We can maybe add a whitespace, so we'll have .split(". ")

Comment: I just checked, that was your answer! :)

Comment: @lulyon I can't post a comment on your answer, but we should always close the opened file (hence why I recommended using with open() as )

Comment: @Elie khalifeh Thank you for the tutorial. REALLY helplful. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Normally sentences are separated by `'. '`, not `'\n'`. Under this condition, use split with `period+space`(without `return-enter`):

```
listed = []

fd = open(filename,"r") 
try:
    data = fd.read()
    sentences = data.split(". ")
    for sentence in sentences:
        listed.append(sentence)

    print listed
finally:
    fd.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! This work for me. Nice and brief as well. Cheers!